# Best way to send all scripts to bottom of page, when having jQuery in bottom as well?

Tags: jquery, performance, asynchronous, delayed-execution

What's the best way to delay all JavaScript to after jQuery is loaded, when jQuery is placed in the bottom of the page? I already solved picking up all the jQuery instances and initiate them after jQuery has loaded, but I need to find a nice way to pick up all external references done with `<script src="file.js"></script>`.

**In `<head>`:**

This grabs all the jQuery functions found on the page, and pushes them into an array.

```
<script>
window.q = [];
window.jQuery = function (f) {q.push(f)};
</script>
```

**Before `</body>`:**

Just before the body, I get jQuery library from Google API with local fallback, then run each jQuery function in the array.

```
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js\"><\/script>')
// after jQuery loaded
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery.each(q, function (index, f) {
        f.call(document);
    });
});
</script>
```

**To the question...**

So I initially had a bunch of `<script>` tags in my code. An easy way to do it is to just call them with jQuery.ajax() and type "script" as shown in the example below, but I'd like to explore the possibilities for better options.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/scripts/somescript.js", // contains myFunction();
        cache: true,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function() {
            myFunction();
        }
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

- This will only be done for uncommon scripts that is not used on every page. It's in a context of widgets that can be turned on or off by the site administrator, which is why I'm not combining it with the rest of the common JS that I've put below the jQuery in my masterpage (MVC).
- I've set this up using html5boilerplate with a few modifications, so I actually got one script in the head which would be Modernizr 2.0.

Let me know your ideas and thoughts for improvements!

Thanks!

Comment: Note: Your first method will break jQuery's chainability, eg: `$(document).load(..).unload(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question right,

executing javascript when the document is ready(aka `$(document).ready()` ) only slows the down page loading, since the browser executes the javascript as soon as it reads it, put jquery as first `<link href...>` and then all the javascript code you want,

note that if javascript tries to use html that's beneath it, it will not work(since the document is still loading, still downloading), so place it at the right position

Comment: yea, but <script src=""></script> is blocking. I'm looking for a non-blocking approach..